# NSScrollView resize automatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

I have a `NSScrollView`, which I would like to resize automatically.
I would send a method to it's `documentView` to get the size of it, like in a `table view` I would calculate and return the required size of the rows.

My problem is, when?
How can I figure out if the `documentView` of the scroll view has been resized?

Has anyone an idea how to do this?
Which methods do I have to override?

I'll publish the project on Github if I figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any NSView or a subclass will call `-viewWillStartLiveResize` and `-viewDidEndLiveResize` when resizing begins and ends.
[NSView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html)

Or, if you're interested in knowing when the window is resized:
[Stack Overflow: get window height/width in real-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604143/get-window-height-width-in-real-time)

Comment: Sorry, I never saw your comment. You didn't add the @ to address it to me. But thanks :)